# How can I trigger an Azure Function based on Application Insights messages with C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I want to create an Azure Function that changes some records in an external database when a certain message appears in the Application Insight logs. To be more specific: I want to trigger it when a "new" registered device (a device that has been reset) starts for he first time. In the database, I then want to attach the device to the logged-in user.

I currently have 2 solutions in mind:

- Create something that triggers the function when a certain message appears.
- Create a timed function (15 minutes or so) that check the logs for a certain message.

I'm not sure if the first one is even possible. For the second solution, I can't find a solution to be able to read the logs in Application Insights.

Does somebody know how I can create a script that reads the AppInsight logs and search for specific messages?

Comment: The process in general how I would approach.  In Azure portal App Insights select Logs.  If you can get a Log query that will select the App Insights entries you want then from there you can create an Alert Rule.  In that Alert Rule you can create an Action Group that can call an Azure Function or Logic App (among other things).  You can specify how often the Alert Rule runs.

Comment: Detecting something gets logged in App Insights, and then doin some db insert based on it - this is so `error prone` and poor design. App Insights logs can be `sampled` and you _may not_ get the message that you are looking for. You should consider whatever is logging to app insight, should really call your API [can be Azure function app] or send a message to an Azure queue[blob storage or Service Bus based].

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is the most elegant solution, but it should work. Create a Diagnostic Setting and choose to stream the events to Event Hub or a storage account, and trigger the function for there. You'll have to do some filtering to find the message type you're looking for, and discard the ones that don't match.

[image]